# Add values not present in list object based on lookup table

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a domain object like so,

```
class PGRatingConfig {
   // other fields
   private List<Rating> rating;
}

class Rating {
   String id;
   String value;
}
```

I have a lookup table for product groups like so

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.add("1", "Soap");
map.add("2", "Cleaner");
```

I'm fetching this `List<PGRatingConfig>` from database and it won't always contain all the data from lookup table. For instance, it would return one `PGRatingConfig` for `soap` having `Rating` as

`PGRatingConfig`

```
// some fields
Rating [
pgId: soap
value: 3
]
```

I want to add the other value from lookup table for `Cleaner` with a default value of `3`. The `PGRatingConfig` would now look as

```
 // some fields
    Rating [{
    pgId: soap,
    value: 3},
    {pgId:cleaner,
     value: 4
    }
    ]
```

How would I add these?

Comment: Why does soap have a separate id and value while `cleaner` seems to be a field name itself?

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate over the entries of the map and add them.

```
PGRatingConfig pg = <some defined instance with some products added>

for (Entry<String,String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    pg.addRating(new Rating(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue())); 
}
```

Here is what the modified classes might look like

```
class PGRatingConfig {
   // other fields
   private List<Rating> rating;
   public void addRating(Rating r) {
      rating.add(r);
   }
   // other methods as needed
}

class Rating {
   private String id;
   private String value;
   public Rating(String id, String value) {
      this.id = id;
      this.value = value;
   }
   // getters
}
```

Note:  To add entries to the map use `put` and not `add`